# How to manually focus using the sony camera SDK over wifi

Tags: sdk, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Sony has released a rather comprehensive API for wifi control of their selection of cameras here:  https://developer.sony.com/downloads/camera-file/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/

I have been searching for what methods to use so I can manually control focus.  I have been able to set the focus mode into "manual focus", but I don't see any methods for setting the focus point.  There are several methods for controlling zoom, which I would expect the same to exist for focus --  Yet, this feature is seemingly implemented in the sony playmemories android application, so it must be possible, I think... but as it's a black box it's hard to tell what focus mode it's calling.

Could someone share what the methods are for manually focusing the camera?  I am on a sony a7r with the lovely 90mm macro.

The beta SDK from March 15, 2016 provides no information on how to do this. This is a key feature which is directly blocking my ability to do effective deep focus stacking.

Answer (score 1):

Deep focus stacking sounds great! But unfortunately, manually focus controlling is not provided by the APIs.

Once you set "Manual Focus" option, you can move focus by using focus ring on lens. (Don't ask me why Sony added such option to the API for Wi-Fi devices!)